# PF('DataTable').filter() Auto filter is so slowly Primefaces 5

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm working with `dataTables` and I need to do and `autofilter` I've a custom `dataTable` to [persist the filters](http://stickysession.com/2013/02/extending-primefaces-datatable-to-enable-persistent-filter-values/)

So I've a page with:

```xhtml
<p:remoteCommand name="onload" oncomplete="PF('myTable').filter()" autoRun="true"/>

<p:dataTable id="tabla_" 
    var="aval"
    value="#{listadoBean.avals}"
    selection="#{listadoBean.aval}" 
    rowKey="#{aval.id}"
    selectionMode="single" 
    sortBy="#{aval.fecha}"
    sortOrder="descending"
    widgetVar="myTable"
    resizableColumns="true"
    scrollWidth="1400"
    scrollHeight="420"
    scrollRows="15"
    filterMap="#{listadoBean.filterMap}"
    scrollable="true">

   ...columns...

</p:dataTable>
```

The problem is when load the page, shows the original values, and take 5 seconds or little more to do the auto filter, I'm  wondering if is possible increase this time or render the `dataTable` in other way to render the `dataTable` faster?

Comment: How many rows do you have? Is the DB getting contacted during the filtering? (you can turn on logging of all sql in persistence.xml)

Comment: Yes, maybe your code is slow... do some profiling. And did you have a look at the PrimeFaces showcase? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml